# In a php class, Can I use the same name for a funcion parameter and a public property?

Tags: php, oop, class, function, parameters

Does php differentiate them or should I use different names? This is wrong in oop but maybe php is very user friendly.

Comment: Please edit your question. Do not rely on the question title to ask the question. Ask the question in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access object properties using the [`$this->property`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) syntax. They are not aliased or appear in the local scope. Thus PHP cannot confuse a function parameter with an object variable. Two different notations.

```
 public function whatever($parameter) {

      $parameter != $this->parameter;

 }
```